# android studio "open declation" switching to R.java

Tags: declaration

In eclipe when you press "ctrl+click" on a R.layout.main from a java file it will switch to
    the main.xml file. But in android studio it is switching to R.java file. How to do the same
    in Studio. Some of them told about f3, Ctrl+t, Ctrl+b. But non of this is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After update the Android studio to 1.5 and above version, this issue was fixed.